# I cannot make UDP Ports work on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: sockets, networking, azure, udp, virtual-machine

I cannot receive a UDP packet on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine. I have done the following:

1. On the Virtual Machine, via Windows Firewall, I opened up Port 1234* both Inbound and Outbound for both UDP and TCP protocols. I did not add any IP exclusions. The rule should apply to Domain, Private and Public profiles. I am allowing Block Edge Traversal.
2. In the Azure Management Portal, I added Endpoints for my Virtual Machine instance. I added both UDP and TCP protocol endpoints. Public and Private port numbers are both 1234.

I have two test programs that I wrote: UDPSender and UDPReceiver. Using two computers on my local network, the test programs successfully sent a packet between them. (Edit: I also used [UDPTester Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.synprez.udp_tester) to successfully send a 'trans-ISP' message to my PC running the UDPReceiver.)

Moving UDPReceiver to my Virtual Machine, I cannot successfully receive a message.

Did I miss anything in my Azure Endpoint configuration? Please Help!

`*` Port Number changed to protect the innocent.

---

Test Program Code Below...

---

**UDPSender:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textMessage.Text = "Knock, knock";
        textIP.Text = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        textPort.Text = "1234";
    }

    private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(textIP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textPort.Text));
        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textMessage.Text);
        try
        {
            udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**UDPReceiver:**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Creates a UdpClient for reading incoming data.
        UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(1234);
        while (true)
        {
            //Creates an IPEndPoint to record the IP Address and port number of the sender.
            // The IPEndPoint will allow you to read datagrams sent from any source.
            System.Net.IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 0);
            try
            {

                // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
                Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                string messageOut = String.Format("[{0},{1}]@[{2}]: {3}",
                    RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString(),
                    RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString(),
                    DateTime.Now,
                    returnData.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine(messageOut);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks correct. I compared it against my implementation. Here are the key sections for reference:

Your csdef should have the correct port protocol. You said you did this through the portal, but confirm the settings saved:

```
<Endpoints>
    <InputEndpoint name="UdpEndpoint" protocol="udp" port="8080" localPort="8080" />
</Endpoints>
```

(from https://github.com/ytechie/LogHub/blob/master/Microsoft.LogHub.Cloud/ServiceDefinition.csdef)

And listening on the correct port was as easy as:

```
var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
var udp = new UdpClient(8080);
```

(from https://github.com/ytechie/LogHub/blob/master/Microsoft.LogHub/Global.asax.cs)

Feel free to take a look at my implementation and look for differences. I did notice that you're using the synchronous version of "Receive", but that shouldn't matter.

I'm also curious if this is PaaS or IaaS. In either case, you'll need to hit against the load balanced endpoint, and not an internal endpoint which would be inaccessible from the internet.

Comment: I should be clear that I am not deploying my service/exe as a Cloud App. I have deployed a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine and have installed the app I wish to run on that machine. 

Do I still need a csdef file for a winforms executable installed on a virtual machine?

Eventually I'd like to deploy this as a cloud service, but there is a bit of a learning curve to overcome before that happens. Likewise, nothing beats filling up a multiline textbox in a forms app for debugging. ;)

Comment: Also, no load balancing on any services yet.

Comment: Virtual machines in azure still reside inside of a cloud service. If you view your cloud services in your account you'll see it. That will give you the public endpoint. Even if you don't load balance, there is still a "router" that needs to NAT to your VM. The portal will give you the cloud service address. My first section of code will just get configured through the Azure portal for IaaS (sounds like you did this), and I would just turn off the VM firewall for testing instead of just adding an exception.

Comment: I see the VM as a Cloud Service and I see my public endpoints (including UDP 1234) for that VM / Cloud Service. The good news is that turning off the firewall on the VM works. The bad news is that I still have no idea what I'm going to do when I need to lock down the VM when moving to production.

Where does the csdef file live for a VM? On the VM level? Do I add it to my Winforms project? And, thank you for all your help so far. I've been learning a lot.

Comment: I should have been more clear. A VM has no csdef. A VM instead is configured through the portal exclusively. I was just trying to show that a VM and a PaaS instance both reside in a cloud service, and have similar routing capabilities, even though they can be configured by different means.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer for now. What ended up working in the end was shutting off the firewall completely and then turning it back on again. Eat your heart out, [IT Crowd](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0487831/quotes?item=qt0503532).

Comment: LOL - the golden rule of IT. Turn it off and back on.