# Cannot send UDP datagrams from Azure VM

Tags: azure, udp, virtual-machine

I am trying to send UDP datagrams from an Azure VM which has a public IP and a security group that has Outbound connections setup for UDP (actually for Any protocol) but I do not get the datagrams on the remote computer.

I can receive UDP datagrams on the VM with no issue.

```
Priority Name  Port     Protocol Source Destination Action
100      Any   1-65000  Any      Any    Any         Allow
```

To test I am using UDP Sender/Receiver.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the remote computer is listening on the same UDP port and binds with IP address `0.0.0.0`. Also, the UDP and port should be allowed in the inbound rule in the firewall of remote computer. Please note that **Azure supports the UDP networking protocol but does not support UDP broadcasting**. You could get more explanation in [this blog](http://www.redbaronofazure.com/?p=7343). You could also get more references in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794543/i-cannot-make-udp-ports-work-on-a-windows-azure-virtual-machine).

Hope this information could help you.

Comment: Indeed, Azure is not supporting broadcasting nor multi-casting...